# Change Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip content on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a tooltip on an anchor element, that sends an AJAX request on click. This element has a tooltip (from Twitter Bootstrap). I want the tooltip content to change when the AJAX request returns successfully. How can I manipulate the tooltip after initiation?

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Just found this today whilst reading the source code. So `$.tooltip(string)` calls any function within the `Tooltip` class. And if you look at `Tooltip.fixTitle`, it fetches the `data-original-title` attribute and replaces the title value with it.

So we simply do:

```
$(element).tooltip('hide')
          .attr('data-original-title', newValue)
          .tooltip('fixTitle')
          .tooltip('show');
```

and sure enough, it updates the title, which is the value inside the tooltip.

A shorter way:

```
$(element).attr('title', 'NEW_TITLE')
          .tooltip('fixTitle')
          .tooltip('show');
```

Comment: You can also change the title through the data('tooltip').options property, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181847/how-to-change-placement-of-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-placement-after-initializat

Comment: scroll down (or http://stackoverflow.com/a/20713610/1350306) to change text without closing/reopening the toolip.

Comment: Couldn't find documentation on 'fixTitle', so I guess not a good idea to use this!? ...

Comment: You can safely omit the call to fixTitle: $(element).attr('data-original-title', 'xyz')

Comment: Is there a way to update the text without manipulating the title-attribute?

Comment: I removed tooltip('hide') and tooltip('fixTitle'), and it worked still

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, the tooltip switched values and then disappeared quickly. `$(element).attr('data-original-title', newValue).tooltip('show');` was the simplest working solution for me.

Comment: I was having trouble with the tooltip after using both methods (it was disappearing a not coming back again), it was basically because of the native focus so adding ``$element.trigger('focusout')`` fixed that problem for me.

Comment: In my case @lukmdo solution didn't work properly. I still could see the old title for a moment so the `tooltip('hide')` was useful.

Comment: This works in firefox, chrome, IE and Edge, "$(element).attr('data-original-title', newValue).tooltip('show');" , was indeed the simplest working solution, thanks.

Comment: @fsasvari in bootstrap 4 just change it to '_fixTitle'

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v4.1.2 and I had to use _fixTitle instead of fixTitle

Comment: Bootstrap 4 - noted below - use .tooltip('update');

Comment: $(element).attr('title', 'NEW_TITLE') is enough to update the title

Comment: In my case works without ".tooltip('fixTitle')" just in this way:

$(element).tooltip('hide')
          .attr('data-original-title', newValue)
          .tooltip('show');

Answer (score 123):

In Bootstrap 3 it is sufficient to call `elt.attr('data-original-title', "Foo")` as changes in the `"data-original-title"` attribute already trigger changes in the tooltip display.

**UPDATE:** You can add .tooltip('show') to show the changes immediately, you need not to mouseout and mouseover target to see the change in the title

```
elt.attr('data-original-title', "Foo").tooltip('show');
```

Comment: It not applies changes immediately, you need to mouseout and mouseover target to see the new title text

Comment: This is actually the best answer and you can add `.tooltip('show');` to get it to show after the update

Comment: This is the only solution (out of many tried) that seemed to just work (bs3). Nice solution for sure!

Comment: This solution is better than all others

Comment: why it didn't work when i use single quote as in second parameter around `'Foo'` like `.attr('data-original-title', 'Foo')` ??

Comment: Since Bootstrap v5 it is `data-bs-original-title` instead of `data-original-title`

Comment: the solution rise another issue - tooltip does't get hide on mouseover

Answer (score 21):

Here is update for the **Bootstrap 4**:

```
var title = "Foo";
elt.attr('data-original-title', title);
elt.tooltip('update');
elt.tooltip('show');
```

But the best way is to do like this:

```
var title = "Foo";
elt.attr('title', title);
elt.attr('data-original-title', title);
elt.tooltip('update');
elt.tooltip('show');
```

or inline:

```
var title = "Foo";
elt.attr('title', title).attr('data-original-title', title).tooltip('update').tooltip('show');
```

From the UX side you just see that text is changed with no fading or hide/show effects and there is no needs for the `_fixTitle`.

Comment: The solution worked for me, thanks! 
In general, please note that you can only update tooltips which are enabled. So in case you have manually disabled a tooltip, you have to re-enable it by using elt.tooltip('enable') before updating it.

Answer (score 15):

you can update the tooltip text without actually calling show/hide:

```
$(myEl)
    .attr('title', newTitle)
    .tooltip('fixTitle')
    .tooltip('setContent')
```

Comment: This, with `.tooltip('show')` on the end of the chain, worked for me.

Comment: yeah, `setContent` and `show` does the trick! you can change `data-original-title` directly instead of using `fixTitle`

Comment: Tested on Bootstrap v2.3.1

Comment: Worked for Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 15):

for Bootstrap 4:

```
$(element).attr("title", "Copied!").tooltip("_fixTitle").tooltip("show").attr("title", "Copy to clipboard").tooltip("_fixTitle");
```

Comment: This uses undocumented API. Beware.

Answer (score 13):

heres a nice solution if you want to change the text without closing and reopening the tooltip.

```
$(element).attr('title', newTitle)
          .tooltip('fixTitle')
          .data('bs.tooltip')
          .$tip.find('.tooltip-inner')
          .text(newTitle)
```

this way, text replaced without closing tooltip (doesnt reposition, but if you are doing a one word change etc it should be fine). and when you hover off + back on tooltip, it is still updated.

**this is bootstrap 3, for 2 you probably have to change data/class names

Comment: Says `$tip` is not an attribute of `$(element)`

Comment: Did that: `$(element).attr('title', newTitle).tooltip('fixTitle').parent().find('.tooltip .tooltip-inner').text(newTitle);`

Comment: I'm updating a tooltip on a neighbouring element when typing into a text field, and the tooltip is disappearing for me with this code when I press a key.

Comment: Thanks for this. The only problem with this solution is that it seems to mess up tooltip position after text change.

Answer (score 10):

This works if the tooltip has been instantiated (possibly with javascript):

```
$("#tooltip_id").data('tooltip').options.title="New_value!";
$("#tooltip_id").tooltip('hide').tooltip('show');
```

Comment: With bootstrap 3, it becomes `$('#tooltip_id').data('bs.tooltip').options.title = 'New_value!';`

Comment: Hey relational, could you change your answer to reflect the comments corrections? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

## Bootstrap 4

```
$('#topic_1').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({title: 'Goodbye'}).tooltip('show')
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipdispose

```js
$('#topic_1').tooltip({title: 'Hello'}).tooltip('show');
setTimeout( function() {
  $('#topic_1').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({title: 'Goodbye'}).tooltip('show');
}, 5000);
```

```css
#topic_1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="topic_1">Topic 1</div>
```

Comment: This feels like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 8):

For bootstrap 3.x

This seems like cleanest solution:

```
$(element)
  .attr('data-original-title', 'New title').tooltip('show')
```

Show is used to make title update right away and not wait for tooltip to be hidden and shown again.

Answer (score 7):

You can just change the `data-original-title` using the following code:

```
$(element).attr('data-original-title', newValue);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Bootstrap 5** doesn't have `fixTitle` or `_fixTitle` anymore, so I had to dispose the entire Tooltip object and reconstruct it:

```
$('a.copy').click(function() {
    var tt = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(this);
    tt.dispose();
    this.setAttribute('title', 'Copied!')
    tt = bootstrap.Tooltip.getOrCreateInstance(this);
    tt.show();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Bootstrap 5.3

Bootstrap version `5.3` now has the `setContent` method to change tooltip title after initialization. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#methods

```
var tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance('#elementId');
tooltip.setContent({ '.tooltip-inner': 'another title' });
```

Comment: It is strange, using setContent only hide my tooltip in my case without any error.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked the best for me, basically I'm scrapping any existing tooltip and not bothering to show the new tooltip. If calling show on the tooltip like in other answers, it pops up even if the cursor isn't hovering above it.

The reason I went for this solution is that the other solutions, re-using the existing tooltip, led to some strange issues with the tooltip sometimes not showing when hovering the cursor above the element.

```
function updateTooltip(element, tooltip) {
    if (element.data('tooltip') != null) {
        element.tooltip('hide');
        element.removeData('tooltip');
    }
    element.tooltip({
        title: tooltip
    });
}
```

Comment: Best Answer to this.Question.

Comment: If you're using boostrap3 you need to use `data('bs.tooltip')` instead of `data('tooltip')`

Comment: how do you call this? the parameter element is the element which has the data attributes set to trigger the tooltip, and the tooltip parameter is (?)

Answer (score 3):

In bootstrap 4 I just use `$(el).tooltip('dispose');` then recreate as normal. So you can put the dispose before a function that creates a tooltip to be sure it doesn't double up.

Having to check the state and tinker with values seems less friendly.

Comment: Should we call $(el).tooltip('dispose') before or after updating the tooltip title ?

Comment: @imabot dispose of old tooltip, then recreate with new data. If your tooltips are complex you may want to retrieve or otherwise store the initial config so you can just recreate with that config + new values. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can set content on tooltip call with a function

```
        $("#myelement").tooltip({
            "title": function() {
                return "<h2>"+$("#tooltipcontainer").html()+"</h2>";
            }
        });
```

You don't have to use only the title of the called element.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks this code was very helpful for me, i found it effective on my projects

`$(element).attr('title', 'message').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');`

Answer (score 2):

I change the title in tooltip dynamicaly with ajax.

- first just enable the tooltips:

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
- Then change the title attribute, then re init the tooltip

```html
$("#foo").attr('title','TheNewTitle');
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT use `.tooltip('show')` if you have multiple tooltip that dynamically change, see example below, hover all element below for 1 second then mouseout,  you will see unexpected result

[image]

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').mouseover((e) => {
  let self = $(e.target);
  setTimeout(function() { // ajax call
    self.attr('data-original-title', 'New Value of ' + self.text())
      .tooltip('show');
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
span{margin: 20px;font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 1">Text 1</span>
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 2">Text 2</span>
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 3">Text 3</span>
```

the better way is by editing `data-original-title` and `.tooltip-inner`

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').mouseover((e) => {
  let self = $(e.target);
  setTimeout(function() { // ajax call
    let newValue = 'New Value of ' + self.text();
    self.attr('data-original-title', newValue)
    $('.tooltip-inner').html(newValue)
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
span{margin: 20px;font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 1">Text 1</span>
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 2">Text 2</span>
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text 3">Text 3</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content

```
$(element).tooltip("destroy");    
$(element).tooltip({
    title: message
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the answers working, here's a workaround:

```
$('#'+$(element).attr('aria-describedby')+' .tooltip-inner').html(newTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

For BS4 (and BS3 with minor changes) .. after hours of searching and trials, i came up with the most reliable solution for this problem and it even solves the problem of opening more than one (tooltip or popover) at the same time, and the problem of opening automatically after losing focus, etc.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  trigger: 'hover'
}).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function() {
  var link = $(this);
  var data = '';
  data += '<ul style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;font-size:12px">';
  data += ' <li>Sherif Salah</li>';
  data += ' <li>Muhammad Salah</li>';
  data += ' <li>and a gazillion more...</li>';
  data += '</ul>';
  link.attr('data-original-title', data);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (link.is(':hover')) {
      link.tooltip("dispose").tooltip("show");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="Loading...">gazillion</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only tested this in **bootstrap 4** & w/o calling .show()

```
el.tooltip('hide').attr('data-original-title', 'message');
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to change tooltip content/title ***onclick*** like bootstrap docs. Did you notice when you copy a code example there? I'm using Bootstrap `v5` here...

```
<span id="tooltip" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
title="Tooltip content">Tooltip</span>
```

Make sure you've [enabled](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) the Bootstrap5 tooltip before going to the next step

```
$('#tooltip').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Content changed!').tooltip('show');
  $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Tooltip content');
});
```

When you hover on this **span** element, it will show **Tooltip content**. When you click on it, this will change to **Content changed!** and will return to default title **Tooltip content**.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mehmet Duran is almost right, but there were some problems when using multiple classes with the same tooltip and their placement. The following code also avoids js errors checking if there is any class called "tooltip_class". Hope this helps.

```
if (jQuery(".tooltip_class")[0]){    

        jQuery('.tooltip_class')
            .attr('title', 'New Title.')
            .attr('data-placement', 'right')
            .tooltip('fixTitle')
            .tooltip('hide');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the text by altering the text in the element directly. (does not update the tooltip position).

```
$('.tooltip-inner', $element.next()).html(newHtml);
$('.tooltip-inner', $element.next()).text(newText);
```

Change the text by destroying the old tooltip, then creating and showing a new one. (Causes the old one to fade out and the new one to fade in)

```
$element
.tooltip('destroy')
.tooltip({
    // Repeat previous options.
    title: newText,
})
.tooltip('show');
```

I'm using the top method to both animate the "Saving." message (using `&nbsp` so the tooltip does not change in size) and to change the text to "Done." (plus padding) when the request completes.

```
$element.tooltip({
  placement: 'left',
  title: 'Saving...',
  trigger: 'manual',
}).tooltip('show');

var parent = $element.parent();
var interval_id = setInterval(function(){
    var text = $('.tooltip-inner', parent).html();
    switch(text) {
    case 'Saving.&nbsp;&nbsp;': text = 'Saving..&nbsp;'; break;
    case 'Saving..&nbsp;': text = 'Saving...'; break;
    case 'Saving...': text = 'Saving.&nbsp;&nbsp;'; break;
    }
    $('.tooltip-inner', parent).html(text);
}, 250);

send_request( function(){
    // When the request is complete
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    $('.tooltip-inner', parent).html('Done.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $element.tooltip('hide');
    }, 1500 /* Show "Done." for a bit */);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (bootstrap 3.3.6; jquery=1.11.3)

```
<a id="alertTooltip" href="#" data-html="true" class="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip message"></a>

<script>
  $('#alertTooltip').attr('title', "Tooltip new <br /> message").tooltip('fixTitle');
</script>
```

The attribute `data-html="true"` allow to use html on the tooltip title.

Answer (score 0):

With Tooltip object Boostrap :

```
$(element).attr('data-original-title', 'New value');
$(element).data('bs.tooltip').tip().find('.tooltip-inner').text('New value');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the title attribute in HTML then use on click of the icon or button
**$(this).attr('title',newValue);**

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code to hide the tool tip change its title and show the tooltip again, when the ajax request returns successfully.

```
$(element).tooltip('hide');
$(element).attr('title','this is new title');
$(element).tooltip('fixTitle');
setTimeout(function() {  $(element).tooltip('show');}, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this easy way out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").prop('title', 'Click to copy your shorturl');
});

function myFunction(){
  $(btn).tooltip('hide');
  $(btn).attr('data-original-title', 'Test');
  $(btn).tooltip('show');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).attr('data-original-title', 'click here to publish')
       .tooltip('fixTitle')
       .tooltip('show');
```

Useful if you need to change a tooltip's text after it has been initialized with attr 'data-original-title'.