# How to change placement of Twitter-Bootstrap tooltip placement after initialization?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to change placement of a Bootstrap tooltip on a text box after it has been already initialized:

```
// these don't work
$('#myTextbox').tooltip({ placement: 'left' });
$('#myTextbox').tooltip('options', 'placement', 'right' });
```

Is there any way to do it? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Bootstrap 2.x, the answer is as [ajbeaven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161735/ajbeaven) states:

```
$('#myTextbox').data('tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

However, from Bootstrap 3, all Bootstrap data is namespaced with `bs`:

```
$('#myTextbox').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

Answer (score 19):

Ahh, found the answer:

```
$('#myTextbox').data('tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

Comment: Brilliant...I needed to change the title, and this ".data('tooltip').options.title = message" really helped...thanks!

Comment: Can you consider my situation: 
I launch my tooltip on hover event. Then I changed title with this trick (checked through the console), but the tooltip was not immediately re-rendered. It still had an old title (all time the tooltip was visible). What should I do to re-render the tooltip after initialisation?

Comment: My first suggestion would be not to initialise the tooltip on hover, but when the element that you're hovering over is rendered. If you can't or won't do that, then do something hacky like `$('.element').tooltip('hide'); $('.element').tooltip('show');` or manually change the tooltip content yourself.

Comment: Any idea what should it be in bootstrap3? I tried applying the above code but it would fail in console saying options undefined.

Comment: @noobcode, indigomonkey has posted another answer which should solve this for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Ben Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2432911/ben-cox)'s response, in Bootstrap 4 use:

```
$('#myTextbox').data('bs.tooltip').config.placement = 'right';
```

Comment: Hi, do you know if for Bootstrap 5? I have tried `.options` and `.config` does not work. This error is appear `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')`