# Checking to see if a Bootstrap tooltip is associated with a field?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am creating Bootstrap tooltips dynamically on fields and I'd like to check to see if a given field has a tooltip so I can edit the message instead of creating a new tooltip.

I don't see anyway to do this in the Bootstrap documentation, but I imagine there a way to accomplish this. Anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also don't see any documentation related. But you can check with a jQuery if the tooltip has the attribute data-original-title. This attribute is added by the plugin while initializing the element and is used for the tooltip text content.

```
if ($('.example').attr('data-original-title')) {
    console.log('Tooltip not initialized'); 
} else {
    console.log('Tooltip initialized');
    // Change the tooltip content
    $('.example').attr('data-original-title', 'My new title');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am seeing that items have tooltip function even before I initialize the tooltip on them.

Comment: Yes, it's because tooltip is like a jQuery plugin. It's available but not initialized in the element until passing the options.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see the confusion, I was trying to figure out if a field had a tooltip it, not if the plugin had been initialized in general.

Comment: I see what you're a trying to accomplish. I'll update the response.

Comment: Ah thanks, I ended up checking the existence of data('tooltip'), similar to the method outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181847/how-to-change-placement-of-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-placement-after-initializat, since my tooltips are 100% dynamic.

Comment: You also need to call `tooltip('fixTitle')` to have the tooltip reflect the new title after changing it.

Comment: Actually I think *initialized* and *not initialized* are inverted.

Answer (score 29):

Using Bootstrap 3:

```
var field = $('.example');

if (field.data('bs.tooltip')) {
    // tooltip is initialized
} else {
    // tooltip is not initialized
}
```

Comment: You just made my day!
Thank you :)

Comment: This was PERFECT! thanks man, this is the correct answer for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Method I ended up using just in case it is useful to anyone else,

```
var field = $('.example');

if (field.data && field.data('tooltip')) {
    // tooltip not initalized
} else {
    // it is
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't swap the comments?