# Can't change bootstrap Tooltip title

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've already looked over several posts on stack overflow asking virtually the exact same question yet none of what I found on those questions has helped.  I'm very new to JQuery and Bootstrap so maybe I'm just missing some really simple thing.

I want to be able to to change the title of the tooltip on different elements after the first initialization(ideally multiple times after initialization.)  A simplified version of what I'm dealing with:

```
<canvas id="bag0"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="test">
</canvas>
...
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#bag0').data('tooltip',false)          
                  .tooltip({ title: 'new text'});
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

});
```

This method to change the title was given from posting: [How to overwrite twitter bootstrap tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214324/how-to-overwrite-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip)

The tooltip always reads "test."  I've tinkered with a few others things to no avail.  I suspect I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: From the link you have mentioned, that answer states the in bootstrap v3 it uses data('bs.tooltip') not data('tooltip').

Comment: Oh yeah, i did try that and it didn't work(just tried it again.)  Forgot to change that in the post.

Comment: `$(#bag0').tooltip('destroy').tooltip({title:"new text"})`. How about this?

Comment: @RLam `Uncaught TypeError: No method named "destroy"` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#methods, but `dispose` worked. `$('#topic_1').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({title: 'Goodbye'}).tooltip('show')`.

Comment: @Chloe "Dispose" on BS4 and "Destory" on BS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr("title","NEW TEXT");
```

If you want to for a particular element, say a `<div>`

```
$('div[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr("title","NEW TEXT");
```

Comment: That did, in fact, change the tooltip that is displayed. However, won't that change all instances of tooltip on all elements on the page?  I plan on having many tooltips and want to change them individually.

Comment: Just put the element in selector you want to change `$('YOUR_DIV[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr("title","NEW TEXT");`

Comment: This doesn't change the tooltip title if the tooltip has already been created. You need to call `.tooltip('fixTitle')` after setting the new title for it to take effect, as shown by @help below.

Comment: @UncleArnie `fixTitle` is not valid. `Uncaught TypeError: No method named "fixTitle"` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#methods

Comment: @Chloe This only applies to bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 25):

`$(element).attr('title', 'NEW_TITLE').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');`

Above code might help you.

$.tooltip(string) calls any function within the Tooltip class. And if you look at Tooltip.fixTitle, it fetches the data-original-title attribute and replaces the title value with it.

You can use the element id or class to make it more specific.

- Help :)

Comment: `fixTitle` is not one of the valid listed parameters. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#methods `Uncaught TypeError: No method named "fixTitle"`

Comment: I had the same error as @Chloe in Bootstrap 4; I had to change "fixTitle" to "_fixTitle" to get it to work.

Comment: @TimP See below answer for Bootstrap 4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320836/148844

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
$(element).tooltip().attr('data-original-title', "new title");
```

Source: [github bootstrap issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14769)

Answer (score 7):

## Bootstrap 4

```
$('#topic_1').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({title: 'Goodbye'}).tooltip('show')
```

```js
$('#topic_1').tooltip({title: 'Hello'}).tooltip('show');
setTimeout( function() {
  $('#topic_1').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({title: 'Goodbye'}).tooltip('show');
}, 5000);
```

```css
#topic_1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="topic_1">Topic 1</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Change Bootstrap 4 Tooltip title**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // initilizing Tooltip
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // Get the Tooltip
  let btn_tooltip = $('#my-btn');

  // Change Tooltip Text on mouse enter
  btn_tooltip.mouseenter(function () {
    btn_tooltip.attr('title', 'Default Tooltip').tooltip('dispose');
    btn_tooltip.tooltip('show');
  });

  // Update Tooltip Text on click
  btn_tooltip.click(function () {
    btn_tooltip.attr('title', 'Modified Tooltip').tooltip('dispose');
    btn_tooltip.tooltip('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>Click the button:</p>
  <button id="my-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Default tooltip">Click Me</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#bag0').attr('title', 'new text')
                  .tooltip('destroy') // if you are using BS4 use .tooltip('dispose')
                  .tooltip({ title: 'new text'});
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');

});
```

```html
<canvas id="bag0"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="test">
</canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for similiar case. I change the title in tooltip dynamicaly with ajax.

- first just enable the tooltips:

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
- Then change the title attribute, then re init the tooltip

```html
$("#foo").attr('title','TheNewTitle');
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit too late but my solution to this was to change the data-original-title

$('.sample').attr('data-original-title': 'new title');

This changes the bootstrap tool tip title automatically.