# jquery clipboard plugin and bootstrap 3 tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, clipboard

I'm using clipboard plugin [HERE](https://clipboardjs.com)

I would like to modify the bootstrap 3 tooltip title on clipboard success event but I've an error "TypeError: e.trigger.tooltip is not a function"

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>
      USERNAME : <a href="#" title="Copy" class="btn-copy" data-clipboard-text="foo">foo</a>
      <br />
      PASSWORD : <a href="#" title="Copy" class="btn-copy" data-clipboard-text="bar">bar</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".btn-copy").tooltip({
  placement: 'right'
});

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  e.clearSelection();
  console.log(e.trigger); -->//<a class="btn-copy" data-clipboard-text="foo" title="" href="#" data-original-title="Copy" aria-describedby="tooltip870310">

  e.trigger.tooltip({ title: 'Copied' });
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e371Ltf1/)

How can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all *e.trigger* is a DOM element not a jQuery element.
So you need to wrap it like this *$(e.trigger)*
Here is the working code from there https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803562/5119765 :

```
$(e.trigger).attr('title', 'Copied').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to use attr but without success.

Comment: Using _attr_ will only update the DOM element and not the _tooltip_ object which needs to be refreshed.