# Tooltip script. Need to correct code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.challenge').tooltip({html: true, trigger: 'hover'});

    $('.challenge').mouseover(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var ajaxQueue = $({
    url: "<?=base_url();?>/ajax/challenge_tip",
     type: 'POST',
     cache: true,
     data: {
      'idd': $(this).attr("rel"),
     },
     dataType: 'json',
       success: function(challenge_j) {
         that.tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', challenge_j)
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
       }
  });

  $.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {

    var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

    ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {

      ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
        if (oldComplete) oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);

        next();
      };

      $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    });
  };
});
});
```

it's my first experience with js and i need some help. for tooltips i use bootstrap tooltips.
when cursor hover on link, script send post data to controller and receive callback data.  in the first hover script receives the data, but tooltip doesn't pop up, only the second hover. how i can fix it?

and one more question. can script will send the request only the first mouse hover, and the following hover will use the information from the cache?

and sorry my english ;D

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @mplungjan one doesn't help. I try to explain the problem more accurately. i have list of links. when i hover to link first , tooltip doesn't pop up. when i hover to other link, tooltip pops up, but with data from first link.

Comment: @mplungjan with one script even doesn`t work

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/95b4m/

Comment: @mplungjan i don`t know. js for me as a forest)

Comment: What is data-original-title? sounds like you use another tooltip script to get this value. You will need to re-bind that if you change the title.

Comment: @mplungjan in bootstrap tooltip data contains it the data-original-title. why rebind?

Comment: I have never used bootstrap, but I could imagine that it is not dynamic after it has been assigned - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501921/change-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-content-on-click

Comment: @mplungjan I've tried everything but nothing helps. maybe if you look what I get, then you can better understand what I want. look warthunder-db.ru/challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to test cross domain

Here is what I THINK you need

```
$(function() {
  $('.challenge').tooltip({html: true, trigger: 'hover'});

  $('.challenge').mouseover(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
     url: "<?=base_url();?>/ajax/challenge_tip",
     type: 'POST',
     cache: true,
     data: {
      'idd': $(this).attr("rel"),
     },
     dataType: 'json',
       success: function(challenge_j) {
         that.tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', challenge_j)
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: wow! cool, but one little problem. with repeated cursor hover repeated request to the server and tooltips doesn't show correctly. u can look it here warthunder-db.ru/challenge

Comment: Hmm, you need [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) then

Comment: i can't understand. why use hoverintent? it only makes the delay to floating tips. i have problems with the lack of cache queries and incorrect display hints during the second hover as you saw.

Comment: The hoverintent will make the hover wait for the user to slow down, so no unnecessary ajax is made on links he is not interested in. So when the user slows down, the ajax is executed but not on the next link he moses ove

Comment: Do you have another option? this version I do not like.

Comment: you need to then queue the ajax instead so they do not fall over each other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done/3710359#3710359

Comment: I apologize for a lot of questions. i'm a little stupid) i updated code in first code, check it (don`t work).

Comment: Sorry, never needed ajaxqueue

Answer (score 0):

Create flag for ajax query.

```
var isTooltipTextEmpty = true;

$('.challenge').mouseover(function(){

    if(isTooltipTextEmpty) {

     ...add ajax query here)

    }

}
```

And you need to trigger tooltip show event, when ajax query is ready like this

```
.success(data) {

     $('.challenge').show();
     isTooltipTextEmpty = false; //prevents multiple ajax queries

}
```

See more here: [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)