# Changing tooltip title using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help me out, as I am new to jQuery & web development.
My requirement was to ellipsize(...) the long text in text boxes
and then if mouse is hovered over them display the full text in tooltip.

For this I used Bootstrap's tooltip .
What I did was the following :

Downloaded bootstrap js and included in my file like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Changed my elemnt like this

```
<input type="text" name="tooltip" id="samplebox" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ankit" >
```

For Dynamically updating the title, I made use of jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(" #samplebox ").mouseenter(function(){
            var word = document.getElementById("samplebox").value;
            $(" #samplebox ").attr('title', word);
        });     
    });
</script>
```

This works fine for that one element.

now I have to do the same thing for more text-boxes, whose number can keep on increasing. Now, I want to create a generic function where I can pass the id
of that element and get it done for any textbox over which mouse is hovered.

Comment: How about a jquery plugin?  Full tutorial here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Take a look at this
[change tooltip title dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090690/5609501)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there are no style classes, use the [attribute-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). For a tooltip, there's also the attribute value of `data-toggle="tooltip"`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").mouseenter(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.val());
    });   
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1vxv4uq/)**

Note: For the use with Bootstrap's tooltip you may have to change the attribute `data-original-title` instead if `title` to update the content of your tooltip. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9501921/4202224)

Answer (score 4):

None of the codes above worked for my bootstrap tooltips.
However, changing the `data-original-title` fixed the issue:

```
document.getElementById("samplebox").setAttribute("data-original-title", "newText");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use class selector like this

```
<input type="text" name="tooltip" class="samplebox" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ankit" >

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".samplebox").mouseenter(function(){
            var word = $(this).value();
            $(this).attr('title', word);
        });     
    });
</script>
```

This will fire the event on all the text boxes you dont need to create any generic function

Comment: Nice. Rather than call the 'generic function' for each textbox, you mark each textbox that it should be affected by startup function.

Comment: assign unique id's as required but also assign a same class name on all those textboxes you want the event to be fired

Comment: var word = document.getElementById("samplebox").value;  use jquery this operator to get the text

Comment: replace document.getElementById('samplebox').value; with this function $(this).value()

Comment: I am using class selector

Comment: Hey bro I copied the sorcecode of the question and forget to make edit in the getting and setting the value... i changed it 5 mins ago please revise the answer

Comment: This is very good.  The only thing is that in jquery $(this).value(); should read $(this).val();

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":input").mouseenter(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   $(this).attr('title', val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First add common class to every textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="tooltip" class="myclass" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ankit" >
```

Then jQuery seems like this.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myclass").mouseenter(function(){
            var word = document.getElementById("samplebox").value;
            $(this).attr('title', word);
        });     
    });
  </script>
```