# Jquery prop only working on first 'mouseover' event

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap tooltip to show the title of a map marker on mouseover. I am using 'prop' to set the title.

The problem is that the tooltip title attribute remains set as the first marker you mouseover.

```
markers[id].addListener('mouseover', function () {
    console.log(markers[id].title);
    /* get marker pixel position */
    var proj = overlay.getProjection();
    var pos = markers[id].getPosition();
    var p = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(pos);
    /* show tooltip */
    $("#tooltip").css("left", p.x + "px").css("top", (p.y + 20) + "px").prop('title', markers[id].title).tooltip('show');
});
```

Please see fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n8x6r5kt/1/

Comment: The issue is that once the tooltip is initialized, it has the title stored and is not fetching it from the `title` attribute every time it displays. If you want to change the title of the tooltip without destroying it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501921/change-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-content-on-click

Comment: @Stryner ah yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, there is one elementary problem with what you're doing, and that is your understanding of how bootstrap `.tooltip()` works. 
Anyhow, below is what you can do, remove the element and reinsert it i.e.

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function () {

    var tooltip = $('#tooltip');

    /* get marker pixel position */
    var proj = overlay.getProjection();
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    var p = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(pos);

    //recreate tooltip
    tooltip.remove();
    tooltip = $(' <div id="tooltip" title="'+ marker.title+'"></div>');
    $('#map').after(tooltip);        

    //add new orientation
    tooltip.css({"left": p.x + "px", "top": (p.y + 10) + "px"});

    tooltip.tooltip();
    tooltip.tooltip('show');

});
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8x6r5kt/2/)

Other options that you can try is

1. Create individual tooltip containers for individual markers, that will save your extra processing on mouse hover
2. You can simply use google maps marker `infowindow` and inject your own custom (looking like bootstrap tooltip) html to it, why reinvent the wheel?(highly recommended)

Comment: 1. I will be showing up to 2048 markers, would you still recommend?
2. I will be using the infowindow for additional content.

Comment: ohh, so content 1 on mousehover and content 2 on click, no no, you are fine then :)