# Dynamically change bootstrap tooltip placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to change the tooltip placement dynamically but it does not work.

```
<input type="text" id="sample" title="Tip">
<button name="change me" id="changeBtn">Change Tool Tip!</button>
```

And for js:

```
//Initiall tooltip for all elements
$("[title!='']").tooltip();

$("#changeBtn").click(function () {
    //Change tooltip placment
    $("#sample").tooltip({placement : 'left'}).tooltip('show');

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znvv9ar5/

I found a good answer at [Change Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip content on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501921/change-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-content-on-click) which shows how to change tooltip text dynamically by using `tooltip('fixTitle')` method. But could not find something for placement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Bootstrap 2.x, the answer is:

```
$('#sample').data('tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

However, from Bootstrap 3, all Bootstrap data is namespaced with bs:

```
$('#sample').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

**Code:**

```
$("#changeBtn").click(function () {

    $('#sample').data('tooltip').options.placement = 'left';
    $("#sample").tooltip('show');

});
```

[Play it here](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/znvv9ar5/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using "destroy" on the tooltip and bind it again

```
$("#sample").tooltip("destroy").tooltip({placement : 'left'}).tooltip('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not like using !important it does help to cheat a little in this case.

```
.tooltip {
    left: 12px!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znvv9ar5/1/ as a result.

You can apply this CSS with the on click.