# bootstrap tooltip - use jquery to dynamically change css & placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.5 and JQuery v1.11.3 .

I have a select list that when a value is selected, I would like the placement and css class of a tooltip to change.

I have searched Google & SO and read many SO posts, but the many attempts I have made fail. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781823/dynamicly-change-bootstrap-tooltip-placement) did not work for me.

Here is my html code:

```
<select id="id_cover_letter_type" name="cover_letter_type">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">I will write my own data</option>
    <option value="1">Standard Cover Letter</option>
    ....
</select>

<i id="id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph" class="fa fa-lightbulb-o blue_color icon_size26 verticalAlignTop" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip229278"></i>
```

Here is my jquery code:

I have included the commented out attempts that I have made to change the data-placement of the tooltip (taken from other posts) that did not work for me.

```
$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip({'html': true, 'placement': 'bottom', 'title': '{% trans "Paragraph 2" %} <br /><br /> {% trans "This should detail why you want the job." %} <br /><br /> {% trans "Explain how your qualifications and career plan match the advertised position." %} <br /><br /> {% trans "The details you provide here should display that you have researched the employer, what the employer and industry are seeking and that you understand what the job requires." %}'});

if ( $('#id_cover_letter_type').val() == '0' ) {

    // the following code did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'left';

    // the following code did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').tooltip({ placement: 'left' });

    // the following, destroying, appling the placement and then showing the tooltip did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').tooltip('destroy');
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip({'placement':'left'});
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip('show');

    // applying the placement and the showing the tooltip did not work.
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip({placement : 'left'}).tooltip('show');

} else {

    // the following code did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'bottom';

    // the following code did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').tooltip({ placement: 'bottom' });

    // the following, destroying, appling the placement and then showing the tooltip did not work.
    //$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').tooltip('destroy');
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip({'placement':'bottom'});
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip('show');

    // applying the placement and the showing the tooltip did not work.
    //$("#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph").tooltip({placement : 'bottom'}).tooltip('show');

}
```

Also, if someone can tell me the answer to change the css of the tooltip to class name `custom-tooltip-styling123`, that would be fantastic.

**EDIT**

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6233114/45nor73y/). This is only my 2nd fiddle, and I don't know how to add in the bootstrap to make the tooltip display.

Comment: So when you select a option the tooltip class will be changed?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for the same

Comment: Jim Fahad, yes tooltip class and tooltip data-placement will change.

Comment: Ankur140290 - I have added a fiddle in the post.

Comment: you can learn more about -The Tooltip plugin is small pop-up box that appears when the user moves the mouse pointer over an element:http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The main problem**

You forgot to add `id="id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph"` to your `img` element.

Also you need to wrap your js code by the following one:

```
$(function () { // On document ready wrapper
    // your code ...
});
```

And the last point is to add tooltip initialization:

```
$('#id_icon_id_cover_letter_details_second_paragraph').tooltip();
```

For full code just check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45nor73y/1/)

**How to change css of tooltip**

There are several solutions you can find on stackoverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color) for example.
`tooltip` has option `template` which default value is:

```
'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
```

You can add `CUSTOM_CSS` and pass updated version of this option, for example:

```
'<div class="tooltip CUSTOM_CSS" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
```

Or you can define your own css rules for `.tooltip` class.

Actually there are more solutions. It's your choice, choose one of them. You know html structure and classes of `tooltip` element, so manipulate it as you wish.

For more info about `template` option requirements check the official documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: Rashad, thanks. I was looking at this so long I could no longer see the error. Do you know how to change the css of the tooltip, so I can change the width between the different placements?

Comment: Oh, you edited your comment. So to change width you just need to define it in css rule. For example `.tooltip.right { width: 300px; }` will change width for the right placement, and `.tooltip.bottom { width: 300px; }` will change width for the bottom placement, and the same thing for the left and top placements.