# How to display different titles for the Tooltip (Bootstrap) and to html validate the form?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I try to show two different title for the Tooltip (Bootstrap) and a standard html validation forms.

Sample code to http://jsfiddle.net/00kvznLu/

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" class='containter'>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Do it here..." pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Check Form">
  </div>
</form>
```

But for some reason, I do not Tooltip displays as well as on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Is it possible to make so that when you move the computer mouse was shown title = "messages1", and the derivation of error "pattern" to the standard message "Enter the data in the specified format." added title = "messages2"?

Is it possible to do like this `tooltip-title="messages1"` and `error-pattern-title="messages2"`?

Bootstrap Tooltip:

[image: title 1]

Error message:

[image: title 2]

**Update 1:**
Added `data-title="Custom Title"`

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" data-title="Custom Title" title="Do it here.." id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
```

Comment: Do you mean change the tooltip if the form isn't valid on submission?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I want to display two different messages in two different places (added image, I hope it will be clear).

Comment: is this ok? http://jsfiddle.net/00kvznLu/1/

Comment: @Reddy in your code you have corrected display Tooltip, but the message is no longer displayed along with an error message (the second image circled in red)

Comment: @Kolya_Net let  me know if my answer helps.

Comment: @Reddy Almost all true. Added data attribute http://jsfiddle.net/e278e33w/  I got what I wanted. Would you change your answer, then I have it confirmed.

Comment: @Kolya_Net sure but why selecting from the data attribute, It will affect your entire site which has that attribute. I suggest using the Id to apply the tooltip as it will target only that element. But if you want to target many other elements then a class selector would be best choice. Only if you want your entire site to have the tooltip title same as this input title then what you suggest works. But I recon that's not what you want. right??

Comment: @Kolya_Net I got your point. But do consider my explanation too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below script. Trick is to apply a tooltip to the parent tag of the input. Let me know if this helps. **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/00kvznLu/8/)**

```
$(function () {
  $('#inputTwitter').parent().tooltip({
   title : $('#inputTwitter').data('title')
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this:

```
var newValue = 'This is a new message';
$(tooltip-selector).attr('title', newValue)
    .tooltip('fixTitle')
    .tooltip('show');
```

I suggest you to use `data-original-title` instead of `title`
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/00kvznLu/4/)

Check @Mehmet Duran [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875490/1151408)