# Update Boostrap Tooltip dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Tooltip. I have enabled the Tooltip html to allow me to use the html span in the `title` attribute.

I am having problem updating the value in the span dynamically.

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38497/

If you click on Update Tooltip button, the tooltip should change to: `10 x 20`

What went wrong?

jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      html: true
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.update', function() {
       $('.a').text(10);
       $('.b').text(20);
    });
  });
```

html

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<span class='a'>2</span> x <span class='b'>5</span>">
  Hover Me
</a>

<button class="update">Update Tooltip</button>
```

Comment: Problem is that the tooltip text isn't HTML, it's just text so jQuery won't find it.

Comment: @DavidG Ah ok. Please answer with possible solution.

Comment: [**This may help you!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875490/3452741) , Good luck :)

Comment: @SamBoHamdan Not really, I need have availability to find selector in tooltip text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.a` and `.b` are not the elements in DOM. They get created only when you try to hover on the tooltip.

So instead of changing that, just change the `a` `data-original-title` to the updated text.

For ex:

```
$('body').on('click', '.update', function() {
       $("a").attr("data-original-title", "<span class='a'>10</span> x <span class='b'>20</span>");
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38499/)

Comment: I can't rewrite whole span block in my case. Maybe get data-original-title string and convert to dom and then find `$(dom).text(10);`?

Comment: Can I know why you cant get that span? I doubt that the approach you suggesting will not work,

Comment: something like that I meant https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38501/ - couldnt get it work yet.

Comment: You are anyway accessing and writing it. Then why to preserve the span instead just overwrite it completely.  Something like https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38502/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/DTcHh/38503/ Updated fiddle. Not sure whether this was meant or not. @I'll-Be-Back

Answer (score -1):

Change `$('body').on('click',...` to `$('.update').on('click', 
function(){ 
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr('title', '10 x 20');
});`.

Comment: Are you sure? did you test before posting answer

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back You are right. I'v fixed my answer. :/