# tooltip data doesn't update

Tags: html, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone know why the tooltip here doesn't update? When I change the title, it should update. Is there something wrong? How can I solve this?

```
<div class="title" [innerHTML]="shortedTitle(page.title) | englishMarker" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{page.title}}"></div>
```

[image]

here is the image of output

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip needs to be updated programmatically once the title attribute has been changed, it will not automatically render changes made to the div.

Solution from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501921/change-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-content-on-click);

```
$(element).attr('title', 'NEW_TITLE')
      .tooltip('fixTitle')
      .tooltip('show');
```

Comment: @ammarammary My apologies, I had included the wrong link in my answer; it has now been updated with the solution from the correct link, take a look at the answers in the link to see alternatives and get more context.

Comment: @ammarammary if you still require help please update your question or comment the problems you ran into on this answer.